# Return url is loading INTO lightbox with Paypal adaptive payment, not window

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using a simple payment set up on an embedded flow.

Everything works well, except the return and cancel urls are being loaded into the lightbox, not the parent window, so I end up with a greyed out window with the return url page in it, and the user can't do anything.

As an example, here's the exact code from my cancel page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
        <p>Unable to complete payment, due to either a payment cancelation, or an error.</p>
        <p>No funds were transfered.</p>        
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
dgFlow = top.dgFlow || top.opener.top.dgFlow;
dgFlow.closeFlow();
top.close();
</script>

</body>
```

When I check out the console output, it says

```
top.opener is null
```

and it's referring to the line

```
dgFlow = top.dgFlow || top.opener.top.dgFlow;
```

Should the return URL not load into the parent window instead?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: did you ever fix this? Got the exact same problem :(

Comment: Hi Andrew. Here's the working code from my thank-you page:

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script>
if (window != top) {
top.location.replace("https://www.mysite.com");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="center">
 <p>Thanks for your payment!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: thanks... we ended up getting rid of this method, and opting to send offsite. The support for the lightbox version is pretty shocking (and not to mention their tech support!)